# Cache difference btw "/image.png" and "/image.png?xyz"?

Tags: css, image, caching

We need to push a new version of a sprite that is referenced several times in a .css file, so I thought I would append a mock querystring after the filename. However, a coworker claims that you only need to change the first reference as long as everything before the "?" remains the same. I find it hard to believe, but is he correct?

I would do it like this:

```
.class1 {
    background-image:url(/path/sprite.png?xyz=123);
}

.class2 {
    background-image:url(/path/sprite.png?xyz=123);
}
```

He claims you can do it like this:

```
.class1 {
    background-image:url(/path/sprite.png?xyz=123);
}

.class2 {
    background-image:url(/path/sprite.png);
}
```

This should, according to my coworker, result in the same file being used for both classes since the new version of sprite.png will have been cached after the reference in class1.

Comment: Why not use a single class with the sprite assigned and apply it to each element that needs the sprite? Then each element will have another class with the position of the needed part of sprite.

Comment: That's how I would've done it. Unfortunately I came into the project late and refactoring the css is not an option at this point

Answer (score 0):

I've used this technique before. It's better to use Apache to control caches. [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html) is a good place to look into how to achieve this. The image header states its expiry.

**EDIT**

Confirmed. Adding a query string to an image will push the sprite to the user. The danger is that it can cause the particular image to never be cached depending on the browser. This can cause sites to load slower than usual is used for all images or large background images.

I can confirm Firefox will always pull the images each time a site is visited.

Comment: Thanks, but the type of server we use is not something we can change. Also this is not an answer to my question, even though I appreciate the advice.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Ahmed, but my question was whether my colleague's css will show two different images or will it in fact result in the same image being used?

Comment: I see. It will result in the image being cached several times. So the browser will not see `image.png?version=1` as `image.png`. The image will therefore appear as 2 different images until one of them expires and has to up-date again. ONE OTHER NOTE: This is dependant on the browser and how it has been coded so it may be different in Chrome vs. Firefox etc etc.